# breeze handling of browser folder cache of json

Tags: json, caching, odata, breeze, datajs

I'm using breeze with datajs to fetch odata json results.

breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstances({ dataService: "OData" });

I want to ensure the returned json results are resident only in client memory and do not get written to the client folder cache of browser.

How is breeze currently exposing the handling of the json results regarding whether the results are written to a file in folder cache?  This is sensitive data and only should be resident in memory on the calling device. What is the breeze default for this and how would I examine or alter this?

Answer (score 0):

Breeze doesn't do anything special to the results of any query from a browser cache perspective. It simply executes an ajax query and processes the results.

The rules regarding the caching by the browser of any ajax results is something that you would typically handle by having the server tell the client not to cache the results. How this is done depends on how the service was written.

If you are using a WCF DataService for this OData endpoint your code might look something like this:

*Note: I have not tested this code so take it with a grain of salt. There should be more info as to how to set cache headers for an OData service on the Microsoft OData or the Microsoft WCF Data Services site.*

```
public class ODataService : DataService<Foo> {

   protected override void OnStartProcessingRequest(ProcessRequestArgs args) {
       HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
       // or possibly
       // HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Cache-control", "no-cache");
   }

   ... other code here ...
}
```